# unable to start jar file with metaspace parameter

Tags: java, spring, jvm

Here I have a command line to start a jarfile.
And it is correct and was able to start my `application.jar` file.

```
nohup java -jar -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Xmn300M -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 -Dspring.profiles.active=test /data/code/application.jar >> /data/code/logs/application.log &
```

When I tried to add metaspace parameters `‐XX:MetaspaceSize=256M ‐XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M` into my start-up-command, which is showing below:

```
nohup java -jar -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Xmn300M -XX:SurvivorRatio=6 ‐XX:MetaspaceSize=256M ‐XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M -Dspring.profiles.active=test /data/code/application.jar >> /data/code/logs/application.log &
```

the JVM crashed with log`Error: Unable to access jarfile ‐XX:MetaspaceSize=256M`.
Is there any thing that I missed? It seems that JVM not recognizing  metaspace parameters in commandline, and treated it as an illegal jarfile.

The jdk version by `java -version` is showing below:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I don't know those parameters but they look as if preceded by underscores instead of dashes

Comment: Try putting `-jar` before `/data/code/application.jar`. Looks like java doesn't recognize `‐XX:MetaspaceSize=256M` as option for some reason?

Comment: My bad, it is due to typo. `-` which I copied from Google is not in English.......@talex

Answer (score 0):

My bad, copy from google but never check the words,`-` was a wrong word(not in English) which leads to the error. Just type it manually again in English, the problem solved.....